# What is the fastest method for collision detection?

Tags: matlab, collision-detection

I am working on path planning, and I have performed path smoothing for the initial path generated from RRT-connect algorithm. However, the resulted smoothed path is colliding with the obstacle. The question is that "How to perform a collision detection and then locate the collide segment and add a point in the middle of that segment?"
[image]

Comment: You can either to it in pixels (AND of pixelated path with pixelated enviroment should be zero) or you can do line-line intersections if you have polygon descriptions of your enviroment

Comment: @AnderBiguri by pixels you mean do a product and if the result is 0 then a collision exists. But, how to locate the segment in that case? and is it efficient in time to do pixels-based collision detection...as for the line-line intersection, I do not know how to polygon description of environment?

Comment: well, you can do a pixel-wise product, and the index of the collision pixel its its location. For the other, yes you do. You do know how to define a line given 2 points? its just that, but many times.